# How to display result of Custom Object in related list in SFO Side Panel?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, opportunitycontactrole, outlook, connect-for-outlook

In SFO Side Panel when you select any email whose email address is same as contact email address in salesforce,it automatically search the contact and it also display Activity History and Opportunty of the perticualr contact.
This is maintained via 'Contact Role' standrad object which is present on related List in Opportunity.

Our Business removed this Contact Role from Page layout and introduced a Custom Object 'Key Contact Role' which is same as Contact Role with additional functionality.Now Problem is when I search for the perticular contact and if that contact is the part of an Opportunity SFO Side panel does not display the Opportunity Information.
Check the below screenshot:
[image]
This is happening because we are adding that contact On Contact role instead it is getting added on 'Key Contact Role' which is custom object.

Is there any way where I can enable this option on Side Panel?
Is there a way where I can Populate Contact/Opportunity Information of Side Panel without using contact role.

P.S.We can not remove the custom object from salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Your architect will want to review your schema and find a way to link your `Key Contact Role` with `Contact Role`. Ideally, they would have extended `Contact Role` rather than creating `Key Contact Role` from scratch.

Comment: They wanted to introduced some field on Contact Role Page layout.As per salesforce standard functionlituy we can not add any custom fields on Contact Role and can not modify the layouts accordingly.Thats why they introduced Custom Object for Contact Role.
How Can I link 'Key Contact Role' to 'Contact Role'?
Are us suggesting programatic way like when I create a record on 'Key Contact Role' at the same time it creates a record on 'Contact Role' object although it is hidden from page layout?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines. Your architect needs to create a link between those two objects (I'd expect a lookup). Whether it would involve using workflow, a class or trigger to create the relationship is unclear. I can't tell you how best to do it without seeing your schema and the fields involved. You'll obviously want to track the relationship in your new object. When a change occurs in key contact, an update to contact role will also need to be made.